# Find the Laurent expansion of $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z^2-1)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration, laurent-series

Find the Laurent expansion on $0<|z-i|<2$ of:

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{(z^2-1)^2}$$

I would like to try this exercise by imitating another that is similar:

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{(z^2+i)^2}$$

where the Laurent expansion on $0<|z-i|<2$, is:

$$\frac{-i}{4(z-i)}-\frac{1}{4(z-i)^2}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(n+3)i^n(z-i)^n}{2^{n+4}}$$

but I can't get to that expansion. I have used that

$$\frac{1}{4(z-i)^2}=-\frac{1}{4}\frac{d}{dz} \Big (\frac{1}{z+i} \Big)$$

Comment: I think for your first expression a Laurent expansion on $0<|z-i|<2$ doesn't exist. This is because both of the poles $z=\pm 1$ are a distance $\sqrt{2}$ away from $i$.

Comment: Something similar happens for the example you give, too, since one of the poles $z=\frac{-1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$ is a distance $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}} < 2$ away from $i$.